# How to handle multiple dynamic user types in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a problem I have been stuck on for days now and can't seem to find the solution which is becoming very frustrating.

In my models I have `Companies`. Each company has 2 `Group`'s for authentication and authorization: *Supervisor and Non-Supervisor*.

Of these 2 `Group`'s there will be several dynamic sub-groups for each company, which I call `Employee Type`. These `EmployeeType`'s will be able to be created by the Company Admin within the Admin panel then assigned to one of the `Group`s.

To summarize: Each `Company` will have 2 `Group`s. Each `Group` will have unlimited # of `EmployeeType`s. Each `EmployeeType` will have unlimited # of `Users`.

Even though the `Group`s are similar across all companies, the `EmployeeType`s can have a similar name but should not be able to be shared across companies.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ....

class EmployeeType(models.Model):
    ....
    employee_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        default='Server'
    )
    group = models.ForeignKey(
        Group,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
class User(AbstractUser):
    ....
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    employee_type = models.ForeignKey(
        EmployeeType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
    )
```

- How can I make it so that `Company A` can have their own `EmployeeType`s and `Company B` can have their own `EmployeeType`s but the name of an `EmployeeType` in both companies can be the same while also making sure that `Company A` cannot see `Company B`'s `EmployeeType`s

Apologies if it seems very simple but I am confused when the `EmployeeType`s become dynamic. I end up having circular logic when I try this and can't seem to wrap my head around the correct structure of it.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer your questions all at once.

*Is this the correct way to model the dynamic user type creation?* **NO**

`Group/Supervisor` should be a `BooleanField` in `EmployeeType`. It need not be a separate model and a foreign key. It will make your authentication and authorization functions much easier since from what I understand they are only of supervisor True/False nature

`User` should have `EmployeeType` as a `ManyToManyField` since you might want to add More roles/EmployeeTypes to an Employee in the future.

You do not need `Company` `ForeignKey` in User since it will be taken care of through `EmployeeType` `ManytoManyField` Relations

Add `Company ForeignKey` in `EmployeeType` and since you would be removing `Group Foreign Key` from `Company, EmployeeType and User`

So your models should look like this:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ....


class EmployeeType(models.Model):
    ....
    employee_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        default='Server'
    )
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    supervisor = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class User(AbstractUser):
    ....

    employee_type = models.ManyToManyField(
        EmployeeType,
        null=True,
    )
```

Comment: But shouldn't I be using Django's built-in `Group`s for authentication and authorization?

Comment: That's a different part of the story. Yes, ideally you should but sometimes in Enterprise systems Django Group s might not be adequate.

Comment: So to help me understand my frustration here. Normally I should use `Group`s but it doesn't work in this situation. Can you explain why it doesn't work? the `BooleanField` feels very "surface-level" which does not seem right (though I am not anywhere near expert here).

Comment: Django Groups are entities you can use to standardize the role of a user. So by that logic, groups can be used. In your use case, it would require extending the Django Groups into EmployeeTypes and customize them to suit the SaaS nature of your product (inferring from multiple companies) since you need groups to be mutually exclusive for separate companies. As far as `BooleanField` is concerned, if the custom groups (in your case the Supervisor thing) have more attributes, let's say it is a superset of EmployeeTypes, in that case, it makes sense to make it a separate model.

Comment: I will ask a more specific question to dealing with extending user groups to broad and specific employee types.. Thank you.